# Apagando linhas apenas se alguma célula da planilha esteja em branco (usando um script)

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, shell-script

Tenho uma planilha do calc (libreoffice)/Excel (na verdade é um arquivo texto que abri como planilha para facilitar a visualização) que contém algumas células em branco (não a linha inteira):

[image: planilha]

Gostaria de caso alguma célula da direita esteja em branco, a linha inteira seja apagada. São algumas milhares de linhas, assim fica inviável fazer manualmente.

Comment: Esse arquivo é um csv? Se sim, acho que tenho uma expressão regular para você

Comment: @Jefferson Quesado: não é csv mas é fácil salvá-lo como .csv!

Comment: Agora que percebi, no título pode ser que qualquer celular em branco exclua a linha, mas no texto só a célula da direita que exclui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz um teste assim, pra simular suas células em branco:

```
>>> x = [1491828000,1491828180,1491828360,1491828540,1491828720,1491828900,1491829080,1491829260,1491829440,1491829620,1491829800,1491829980,1491830160]
>>> y = ["1", "2", "3", "", "5", "", "", "", "9", "10", "", "12", ""]
```

E gerei um CSV assim:

```
with open('teste.csv', 'a+') as f:
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
            if y[i]: f.write(str(x[i]) + "," + str(y[i]) + "\n")
```

Ficou assim:

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 4):

Queremos selecionar apenas as linhas que tenham duas células preenchidas em um csv. Para isso, podemos usar a seguinte expressão regular :

```
^..*,..*$
```

Estou usando expressões regulares simples, de modo que até mesmo os processadores que não implementam o metacaracter `+` consigam entender. Compatível com `grep` e `sed`.

Usar `..*` tem o mesmo resultado que `.+`: é necessário ter pelo menos um caracter, não pode ser a string vazia. Assim, garantimos que ambas as colunas tenham valor.

Caso se use um separador de colunas diferente do `,` (como em outros [DSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values?wprov=sfsi1)s), só mudar o caracter de separação. Essa solução não garante células generalizadas, onde o separador pode estar dentro de aspas ou escapados.